# Borrar fichero PDF después de mostrarlo con window.open() en Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

estoy llamando a window.open() para abrir y mostrar un fichero PDF y me gustaría poder borrarlo después de que el fichero haya sido mostrado por completo. Tengo puesto un sleep(1000) para que el borrado se retarde y dé tiempo a mostrar el PDF al completo, pero no funciona siempre ya que el tamaño del PDF es variable y tardará más o menos segundos en mostrarlo por completo. El código es el siguiente:

```
alert("El documento PDF ["+respuesta.deRespuesta+"] ha sido creado correctamente.");
window.open(contextPath+'/solicitudes/downloadDocumentacion?rutaContrato='+encodeURIComponent(respuesta.deRespuesta), '_blank');
sleep(1000);
eliminarDocumento(respuesta.deRespuesta);
```

Hay alguna manera de borrarlo después de cargarlo por completo sin usar la "ñapa" del sleep?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo desde el mismo script que carga el PDF

Comment: supongo que te refieres a hacerlo desde la página que abre el windows.open(), verdad?

Comment: Correcto. Si actualmente lees el archivo para mostrarlo, podrías borrarlo inmediatamente al finalizar la lectura.